# Connect Polygon dApp to Wallect Connect using Alchemy RPC Provider

Tags: rpc, ethers.js, decentralized-applications, wallet-connect, matic

We are currently using the **"ethers"** library to connect our dApp to Metamask and to send transactions on the **Polygon** blockchain.

We would like to allow users to connect to the dApp via **Wallet Connect** as well.

**So far we tried this :**

```
import WalletConnectProvider from "@walletconnect/web3-provider";

const provider = await new WalletConnectProvider({
  rpc: {
    137: 'https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/<OUR_ALCHEMY_RPC_PRIVATE_KEY>'
  },
  chainId: 137
});

await provider.enable();
const eProvider = await new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(provider)
```

... but `provider.enable()` never resolves without any error after scanning the QR Code and the connection never gets established...

**We also tried the Polygon dedicated library for WallectConnect** but still were not able to make it work :

```
const WalletConnectProviderPolygon = require('@maticnetwork/walletconnect-provider')

const wcProvider = new WalletConnectProviderPolygon({
  host: 'https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/<OUR_ALCHEMY_RPC_PRIVATE_KEY>',
  callbacks: {
    onConnect: (res: any) => {
      console.log('onConnect', res)
    },
    onDisconnect: (res: any) => {
      console.log('onDisconnect', res)
    }
  }
})
// await alchemyProvider.createWebconnector()
const eProvider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(wcProvider, 137)
```

... but not connection modal is displayed. If we uncomment `await alchemyProvider.createWebconnector()` an ugly distorted modal appears, without desktop options, and again it never resolves after scanning the QR Code...

**Any idea how to make Wallect Connect work with our Alchemy provider ?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I use an alchemy rpc and others rpc but, with web3 instead ethers.

```javascript
    const providerOptions = {
        walletconnect: {
          package: WalletConnectProvider,
          options: {
            rpc: {
              137: "https://polygon-rpc.com"
            }
          }
        },
      };
    
      web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
        cacheProvider: false,
        providerOptions,
      });
```

Here the example:
[codepen Web3modal](https://codepen.io/gringonivoli/pen/Yzvmzjr)

I'll try use ethers in a new example.